# Como fazer uma paginação slug no Cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, paginação

O Cakephp por padrão gera uma paginação com índices, por exemplo:

```
noticias/listar/page:2
```

Gostaria de fazer uma paginação dessa forma:

```
notícias/listar/2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

app/config/routes.php

```
Router::connect('/noticias/:slug', array('controller' => 'noticias',
         'action'=>'listar', 'slug'=> '[0-9a-zA-Z]+'));
Router::connect('/noticias/:slug/:pagina', array('controller' => 'noticias',
         'action'=>'listar','slug'=> '[0-9a-zA-Z]+','pagina'=>'[0-9]+'));
```

NoticiasController:

```
$this->paginate = array(
//outras coisas aqui
'paramType' => 'querystring'
 );
```

View listar:

```
$slug = $this->params['slug'];
$this->Paginator->options(array('url'=> array('controller' => 'noticias',
                              'action'=>'listar','slug'=> $slug),
                                 'convertKeys' => array('page')));
```

Acho que é isso, você precisa definir as rotas do cake para ele entender o que você quer solicitar.

Comment: Dessa forma quando clicar na paginação do site vai mostrar noticias/listar/1, onde o 1 é a primeira notícia cadastrada no banco de dados e se clicar em avançar vai mostrar as outras notícias dessa forma?

Comment: @ThiagoPhilipp , você mantem o mesmo padrão, o que o cake irá fazer é pegar a url não-slug e exibí-la padrão slug.
Agora, se ele vai mostrar a primeira, segunda, ou 10 primeiras, vai depender da configuração que você utilizou no `$paginate`, ex:. `public $paginate = array('limit' => 1`);

Comment: Prezado @Thiago, esta solução lhe atendeu?
Caso sim, marque a como resposta aceita, de acordo com o padrão de uso do stackoverflow...

Comment: consegui resolver, obrigado.